# How to type in a large correlation matrix into R

Tags: r, correlation

I have a lower triangular correlation matrix from a paper and want to type it in R for principal component analysis. Here is the correlation matrix.

[image]

I tried the command

```
M <- diag(15) 
M[lower.tri(M, diag = T)] <-c(1.00, .77, 1.00,.53,.50,1.00,
   ...)
```

However, the R reads the data by columns. I tried to use matrix(c(), byrows=TRUE). It does not work. Appreciate suggestions for asking R to read the data by rows).

Comment: Eric90, it is much better if you add a small example of data to your question rather than a screenshot - preferably one that allows users to copy and paste your example in to a local R session. thanks

Comment: Hi, as the correlation table is from a paper, I do not have the original data.   Here is a small example of the data by rows.                                                                                          
1.00
.77 1.00
.53 .50 1.00
.54 .44 .74 1.00
.54 .48 .91 .82 1.00

Comment: @Eric90, why don't you want to build the matrix by columns? I think it's the easiest way to do it since `matrix()` requires desired numbers of rows (`nrow`) and columns (`ncol`) but does not assume "empty" cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
## For this example, consider the version of your matrix with dim = 6*6
M <- diag(6)

# Lower triangular matrix, without values of the diagonal
M[lower.tri(M, diag = FALSE)] <- c(.77, .53, .54, .54, .30, #1st column
                                   .50, .44, .48, .28,      #2nd column
                                   .74, .91, .72,           #3rd column
                                   .82, 63,                 #4th column
                                   .75)                     #5th column

M[upper.tri(M, diag = FALSE)]  <- t(M)[upper.tri(M, diag = FALSE)] 
M # whole matrix
M[upper.tri(M, diag = FALSE)] <- ""
as.data.frame(M)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. It seems that your solution will drop some inputs. Is there a way to retain all the input while creating the lower triangular matrix?

Comment: Hi, now, I got you right. Please, consider the new edit of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. it works as well. The one suggested by user 20650 is faster since I do not need to type in every number in the large matrix.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fill in the matrix in the correct order is by using the matrix transpose.

Create some data: lower triangular correlation matrix output

```
m <- cor(mtcars[1:4])
m[upper.tri(m)] <- NA
write.table(m, temp<-tempfile(), row.names = FALSE, col.names=FALSE, na="")
```

Read in using standard tools

```
# Change `temp` to the path to your matrix file
inmat <- as.matrix(read.table(temp, fill=TRUE))
# Fill in upper triangle
inmatt <- t(inmat)
inmatt[lower.tri(inmatt, diag=FALSE)] <- inmat[lower.tri(inmat, diag=FALSE)]
```

Check

```
all.equal(cor(mtcars[1:4]), inmatt, check.attributes=FALSE)
```

---

---

Okay as you are reading from an image, to save manually typing you may be able to read the text from the image.

```
library(tesseract)
# Read image
engine <- tesseract(options = list(tessedit_char_whitelist = ".-0123456789"))
text <- ocr("https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHf3z.jpg", engine)
cat(text) # looks okay
cat(text, file=temp<-tempfile())

# Now try to fill matrix
v = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(readLines(temp), " ")))

inmat <- diag(15) # just hard-code matrix dimension
inmat[upper.tri(inmat, diag=TRUE)] <- v
inmatt <- t(inmat)
inmatt[upper.tri(inmatt, diag=TRUE)] <- v
```

To produce

```
inmatt
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6] [,7] [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
 [1,]  1.00  0.77  0.53  0.54  0.54  0.30 0.16 0.36 -0.11 -0.10 -0.02  0.14  0.09  0.21  0.16
 [2,]  0.77  1.00  0.50  0.44  0.48  0.28 0.20 0.34 -0.05 -0.09 -0.07 -0.02 -0.01  0.18  0.21
 [3,]  0.53  0.50  1.00  0.74  0.91  0.72 0.28 0.79  0.08 -0.03  0.22  0.04  0.06  0.15  0.22
 [4,]  0.54  0.44  0.74  1.00  0.82  0.63 0.19 0.56  0.02 -0.07  0.23  0.05  0.10  0.15  0.22
 [5,]  0.54  0.48  0.91  0.82  1.00  0.75 0.26 0.70  0.05 -0.08  0.21  0.07  0.09  0.14  0.22
 [6,]  0.30  0.28  0.72  0.63  0.75  1.00 0.31 0.63  0.20  0.02  0.27 -0.03 -0.03 -0.01  0.23
 [7,]  0.16  0.20  0.28  0.19  0.26  0.31 1.00 0.38  0.03  0.15  0.29  0.23  0.24  0.16  0.29
 [8,]  0.36  0.34  0.79  0.56  0.70  0.63 0.38 1.00  0.14  0.05  0.37  0.11  0.11  0.13  0.18
 [9,] -0.11 -0.05  0.08  0.02  0.05  0.20 0.03 0.14  1.00  0.50  0.44 -0.04 -0.10  0.13  0.03
[10,] -0.10 -0.09 -0.03 -0.07 -0.08  0.02 0.15 0.05  0.50  1.00  0.62  0.37  0.08  0.11 -0.07
[11,] -0.02 -0.07  0.22  0.23  0.21  0.27 0.29 0.37  0.44  0.62  1.00  0.31  0.21  0.28  0.09
[12,]  0.14 -0.02  0.04  0.05  0.07 -0.03 0.23 0.11 -0.04  0.37  0.31  1.00  0.73  0.12  0.10
[13,]  0.09 -0.01  0.06  0.10  0.09 -0.03 0.24 0.11 -0.10  0.08  0.21  0.73  1.00  0.31  0.32
[14,]  0.21  0.18  0.15  0.15  0.14 -0.01 0.16 0.13  0.13  0.11  0.28  0.12  0.31  1.00  0.41
[15,]  0.16  0.21  0.22  0.22  0.22  0.23 0.29 0.18  0.03 -0.07  0.09  0.10  0.32  0.41  1.00
```

---

Another option is to pass an image or url of an image to http://www.free-ocr.com/ which will try to parse. It will create a text doc of the image which you can then read in.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion.  if I can only manually type in the correlation table (the correlation table is from a paper which does not provide the raw dataset and my task is to replicate the results from the correlation table). What might be your suggestions?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed and effective solution.